# value Type data structure not accepting Null Why

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to C#.Net
There is two types of data type one is  reference type and other  is value type.
today I experience that if a create a instance of any value type and assign it to `null` that compiler gives error.means

```
int a = null.
```

I am talking about nullable variables means

```
int? a = null;
```

MY Question is  that why error occcures when we assign `null` to any value type data structure.
Thanks  in advance.

Comment: This could be answered just looking at the [MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and [here for nullable value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: he wacha ekda http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Because all types have an underlying range for there allowed values. For `int` null is not an allowable value by default. Thus, when you attempt to assign `null` to your `int` object you get your 'non-nullable type' error.

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the normal range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information...

I hope this helps.